# Azure databricks data frame count generates error com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file abfss:REDACTED_LOCAL_PART

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have this pyspark script in Azure databricks notebook:

```
    import argparse
    from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
    from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

    spark.conf.set(
    "fs.azure.account.key.gcdmchndev01c.dfs.core.chinacloudapi.cn",
    "<storag account key>"
    )
        

    inputfile = "abfss://raw@gcdmchndev01c.dfs.core.chinacloudapi.cn/test/CODI_Ignored_Hospital_Code.csv"
    outputpath = "abfss://spark-processed@gcdmchndev01c.dfs.core.chinacloudapi.cn/test/CODI_Ignored_Hospital_Code"
    jsonTableSchema = "{'type': 'struct', 'fields': [{'name': 'id', 'type': 'integer', 'nullable': False, 'metadata': {} }, {'name': 'hospital_ddi_code', 'type': 'string', 'nullable': True, 'metadata': {} } ]}"
    pipelineId = "test111111"
    rawpath = "raw/test/CODI_Ignored_Hospital_Code"
    rawfilename = "CODI_Ignored_Hospital_Code.csv"
    outputpath_bad = "abfss://spark-processed@gcdmchndev01c.dfs.core.chinacloudapi.cn/bad/test/CODI_Ignored_Hospital_Code"

    stSchema = StructType.fromJson(eval(jsonTableSchema))

    stSchema.add("ValidateErrorMessage", StringType(),True)

    raw = spark.read.csv(inputfile, schema=stSchema, header=True, columnNameOfCorruptRecord='ValidateErrorMessage', mode='PERMISSIVE')

    raw.createOrReplaceTempView("tv_raw")
    dfClean = spark.sql("""
    select 
        *, nvl2(ValidateErrorMessage, 'failed', 'success') as ValidateStatus, now()+ INTERVAL 8 HOURS as ProcessDate, '""" + pipelineId + "'as ProcessId, '" + rawpath + "' as RawPath, '" + rawfilename + "' as RawFileName" + """
    from 
        tv_raw
    """)
    #dfClean.printSchema()

    dfBadRecord = dfClean.filter(dfClean["ValidateErrorMessage"].isNotNull())
    #dfBadRecord.cache()
    badCount = dfBadRecord.count()
```

And this gives me the error on the last line:

```
badCount = dfBadRecord.count()


    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 21.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 21.0 (TID 39, 10.139.64.6, executor 1): com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file abfss:REDACTED_LOCAL_PART@gcdmchndev01c.dfs.core.chinacloudapi.cn/test/CODI_Ignored_Hospital_Code.csv
```

And detailed error:

```
    Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    <command-3450774645335260> in <module>
         34 dfBadRecord = dfClean.filter(dfClean["ValidateErrorMessage"].isNotNull())
         35 #dfBadRecord.cache()
    ---> 36 badCount = dfBadRecord.count()
         37 

    /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in count(self)
        584         2
        585         """
    --> 586         return int(self._jdf.count())
        587 
        588     @ignore_unicode_prefix

    /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
       1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
       1304         return_value = get_return_value(
    -> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
       1306 
       1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted MS Azure support and they pointed to add .cache() at the end, so use this

```
    raw = spark.read.csv(inputfile, schema=stSchema, header=True, columnNameOfCorruptRecord='ValidateErrorMessage', mode='PERMISSIVE').cache()
```

instead of:

```
    raw = spark.read.csv(inputfile, schema=stSchema, header=True, columnNameOfCorruptRecord='ValidateErrorMessage', mode='PERMISSIVE')
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, these solutions did not work because I am reading a parquet file like below:

```
df_data = spark.read.parquet(file_location)
```

and after applying transformations to the dataframe the spark exception occurred when I try to save:

```
Error in SQL statement: SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file abfss:REDACTED_LOCAL_PART@REDACTED.dfs.core.windows.net/path/myfile.parquet. It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
```

The solution in my case was to run the following command **before** reading my parquet files:

```
sqlContext.clearCache()
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: your source data might have changed during processing.

In my case, we have two separate, sequential batch pipelines in Azure Data Factory, that calls some Azure Databricks notebooks: The 1st for processing the source data from a SQL Server database and convert them into parquets; and the 2nd takes the processed parquets from the 1st pipeline and performs the cleaning, aggregation, and whatnot, saving the cleaned data into another format.

Each of these pipelines are managed by different teams, and these pipelines are not synchronized in any way. The 1st starts at 9AM, usually takes 40 minutes to run, and the 2nd starts at 2PM. We expect that the 1st pipeline has finished running before starting the 2nd.

Today the 2nd pipeline failed because the 1st pipeline actually ran twice: once at 9AM and then again at 2:08PM, so the source parquets were modified during the execution of the 2nd pipeline, and Spark returned this error.

Our solution was to simply run the 2nd pipeline again, and it ran fine. To avoid occurring again we had to find out why the 1st pipeline ran twice, and then change the scheduling of the 2nd pipeline accordingly.

As a takeaway: **sometimes the problem is in the general process, not in your code**.

I hope this particular case helps someone out there.